# Remove the vertical grid lines of a QTableView

Tags: qt, qtableview, qtstylesheets

I have a `QTableView` as shown below:

[image]

I want to remove all the vertical lines from the table. I tried to set the `gridline-color` property equivalent to the `background-color`, but it removed all the grid lines.

I want the horizontal grid lines to stay, and remove the vertical ones. How can I achieve that ?

Answer (score 8):

delegate.h

```
class QLineDelegate : public QStyledItemDelegate
{
    public:
    QLineDelegate(QTableView* tableView);

    protected:
    void paint(QPainter* painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem& option, const QModelIndex& index) const;

    private:
    QPen pen;
    QTableView* view;
};
```

delegate.cpp

```
QLineDelegate::QLineDelegate(QTableView* tableView)
{
    int gridHint = tableView->style()->styleHint(QStyle::SH_Table_GridLineColor, new QStyleOptionViewItemV4());
    QColor gridColor = static_cast<QRgb>(gridHint);
    pen = QPen(gridColor, 0, tableView->gridStyle());
    view = tableView;
}

void QLineDelegate::paint(QPainter* painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem& option,const QModelIndex& index)const
{
    QStyledItemDelegate::paint(painter, option, index);
    QPen oldPen = painter->pen();
    painter->setPen(pen);

    //draw verticalLine
    //painter->drawLine(option.rect.topRight(), option.rect.bottomRight());

    //draw horizontalLine
    //painter->drawLine(option.rect.bottomLeft(), option.rect.bottomRight());
    //above code, line have breakpoint, the following code can solve it well 

    QPoint p1 = QPoint(itemOption.rect.bottomLeft().x()-1,itemOption.rect.bottomLeft().y());
    QPoint p2 = QPoint(itemOption.rect.bottomRight().x()+1,itemOption.rect.bottomRight().y());
    painter->drawLine(p1, p2);
    painter->setPen(oldPen);
}
```

tableview.cpp

```
tableView->setShowGrid(false);
tableView->setItemDelegate(new QLineDelegate(tableView));
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't. There is no option for `QTableView` to do that.

However, you can do something like setting `gridline-color` property to `background-color` (like you did) **and then** setting a border to all the items of your `QTableView`; as you want only the horizontal grid lines, it will look like this :

```
QTableView::item{
    border-top : 1px solid black
    border-bottom : 1px solid black
}
```

Comment: This would cause a "doubled gridline", since each item will have its own top/bottom border. Even if just one of them is used, this will not look good if one decides to add a margin, the border will also be pushed, and will not look like a grid line.

Answer (score 1):

Use setStyleSheet() with QTableView and inside that give **border-right-color** and **border-left-color** to the color that you gave for gridline-color.